# general procedure for processing http requests on servers

Tags: kotlin, http, http-headers

I started focusing on http handling.
As a starting project, I tried to implement a HTTP-Server based on Kotlin by myself.
It is realy rudimentary and starts using sockets.

Now I reached a point where I don't know correct way of processing the client request.
I got the request and processing the startline.
The startline contains the HTTP-method, HTTP-uri and HTTP-version.

The HTTP-uri leads to an exact function on the server which processes the incoming request. So why is the HTTP-method necessary?
I'm thought about the approach to split the URI and link the name like "delete/user/123" of the function "delete", which removes the given user.

Is this approace wrong, or how is this solved in common projects?